# Unbricking Vivo Y97 after flashing wrong recovery.img

Tags: recovery-mode, custom-roms, unbricking, vivo

It all started when I flashed the wrong `recovery.img` on my device. I have two Vivo Y97s with the exact model, version, and specs. I didn't realize that I need to port TWRP first on my `recovery.img` before I can flash it using fastboot. After I flashed the wrong `recovery.img`, my device suddenly wouldn't turn on, couldn't boot up, and couldn't even enter recovery mode. BTW, they are both bootloader unlocked and the other one is already rooted.

Let's say A is the bricked phone and B is working fine. Can I use the backup ROM of B and restore it to A? I'm not gonna use stock ROM.

Answer (score 2):

## SOLVED!

After flashing the ROM of B into A, the phone is unbricked now and it's working perfectly fine.

I've flashed the **system.img** (*this contains the library of Android system*) and also **vendor.img** (*this contains the drivers of all the hardware for the device, like GPU, camera, touchscreen, microphone, audio, and sensors that the apps use*).

Then I reformat the **recovery.img** partition inside the bricked phone since it was the reason why it was bricked.

I've also reformated the **userdata.img** (*as the name says, it has all the user data like contacts, installed apps, screenlock, photos, videos, and other files*) which basically the same as reset factory in settings